# Bandwidth * Delay Product

Tags: networking, tcp, bandwidth

I'm trying to calculate the bandwidth delay product between various hosts, and reading [this wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandwidth-delay_product), I am confused.

From the acticle;

> Residential ADSL2+: 20 Mbit/s (from DSLAM to residential modem), 50 ms RTT
>
> B×D = 20×106 b/s × 50×10-3 s = 106 b, or 1 Mb, or 125 kB.

One of the connections I am testing from, to a test host, is an ADSL2+ connection. It has a downstream sync rate of "11006 kbps", I am guestimating that 10000Kbps is a reasonable theoretical maximum throughput. When "ping'ing" the test host from the ADSL2+ line I get an RTT of 29ms. The test host is connect to the "Internet" with a 100Mbps Ethernet connection.

**Now, here's the confusing part**;
Performing a speed test against the server (it is running a copy of speedtest.net's mini speed test app) I get 9.23Mbps for the downstream. According to that Wiki article, 10000000bps * 0.029s = 290000bps (290 Kbps), which is much less than my 9.23Mbps.

Have I missed something obvious, or is the article wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm trying to calculate the bandwidth delay product between various hosts... Have I missed something obvious, or is the article wrong?

You're only missing the units; when you multiply bps by seconds, you get bits as the units:

10Mbps * .029s = 2900000.0 bits (362500 bytes)

The point of the article is that it highlights what your (scaled) TCP window needs to be in order to avoid delays due to a "long fat network".  Quoting [RFC 1072](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1072):

> Recent work on TCP performance has shown that TCP can work well over
> a variety of Internet paths, ranging from 800 Mbit/sec I/O channels
> to 300 bit/sec dial-up modems [Jacobson88].  However, there is still
> a fundamental TCP performance bottleneck for one transmission regime:
> paths with high bandwidth and long round-trip delays.  The
> significant parameter is the product of bandwidth (bits per second)
> and round-trip delay (RTT in seconds); this product is the number of
> bits it takes to "fill the pipe", i.e., the amount of unacknowledged
> data that TCP must handle in order to keep the pipeline full.  TCP
> performance problems arise when this product is large, e.g.,
> significantly exceeds 10**5 bits.  We will refer to an Internet path
> operating in this region as a "long, fat pipe", and a network
> containing this path as an "LFN" (pronounced "elephan(t)").

In this particular case, TCP needs to give you a scaled window size that is roughly 362KB.  Modern TCP implementations (those that properly implement [RFC 1323](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1323#section-2)) do not suffer from issues related to LFNs.

Comment: That't what you get for skimming over an article and not reading properly. Still thanks for the great additional info!